# Page definition based on name field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, data-driven-pages, definition-query

I'm a basic user of ArcMap and currently trying to figure out a solution for an issue i'm having with my data driven pages. The data frame layer that I'm using for the data driven page has a field with simple numbering 1,2 and 3 which correlate to a specific type of soil that it represents. I'm using this numbering as the page name field and using page definition queries on my other layers to only show attributes that correlate to that specific soil type. The issue is, a couple of other layers which I also need to change with each driven page do not contain that specific numbering as it is not related to soil types but instead it is the location ID, which is basically a redline boundary which would ideally change as driven page changes.

Is there a way I can create a custom page definition query which uses another attribute within the driven page attribute table and not the page name field?

At the moment my only solution to this is to simply use a simple definition query and change the location ID with each map but ideally i'd like this to be a little more automated.

Comment: Do you want the Location ID to show on the page somewhow? That can be done by inserting a dynamic field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is helpful but if you click the "Layers" icon in your table of contents window, go to data frame, and select clip options you can use this as a psuedo definition query which may help with the issue you are having.  I use this often when dealing with multiple different data types that I want to fit to defined layers.